# Reading 2 bytes through I2C

Tags: c, microcontroller, i2c, lpc, nxp-microcontroller

I was writing since I am trying to implement an I2C communication protocol that reads 2 registers (or more) and receives a byte from each register. As far as I know, the writing part is done correctly according to the logic analyzer. The problem is that I only receive one byte repeated twice instead of a byte per register. It's my first LPC/I2C program and I guess there must be some small error somewhere. I attach the read function, the main and the logic analyzer output. I want to read registers 0x28 and 0x29 and receive the acceleration (LSM9DS0 IMU).

I am using LPC1549 Xpresso

Thanks in advance for the help and your time.

READING FUNCTION:

```
uint32_t E2PROM_Read(uint8_t slave_address, uint16_t read_address, uint16_t   bytes_to_read, uint8_t * in_buffer)
{
uint8_t out_buffer[2];
out_buffer[0]=0x0000;
out_buffer[1]=0x0000;

//out_buffer[0] high address
//out_buffer[1] low address
I2CM_XFER_T  i2cmXferRec;

out_buffer[0] = (uint8_t)(read_address);
out_buffer[1] = (uint8_t)(read_address + 0x01);


i2cmXferRec.slaveAddr = slave_address;
i2cmXferRec.status    = 0;
i2cmXferRec.txSz      = 2;
i2cmXferRec.txBuff    = out_buffer;
i2cmXferRec.rxSz      = bytes_to_read;
i2cmXferRec.rxBuff    = in_buffer;




//* Test for valid operation */
        if (i2cmXferRec.status == I2CM_STATUS_OK) {
            /* Output acc. */
            DEBUGOUT("acceleration read over I2C is: \n %d \n %d ",
            (int) in_buffer[0], (int) in_buffer[1] );

Chip_I2CM_XferBlocking(LPC_I2C0, &i2cmXferRec);



return i2cmXferRec.status;
// .status = 0 if ok
    }
        else {
                DEBUGOUT("Error %d reading temperature.\r\n", i2cmXferRec.status );
            }
}
```

Call to the function:

```
uint8_t in_buffer[10];
uint8_t read_address=0x28;
E2PROM_Write(I2C_TEMP_ADDR_7BIT, 0x20, 2, out_buffer1);

E2PROM_Write(I2C_TEMP_ADDR_7BIT, 0x21, 2, out_buffer2);
/* Loop forever, toggle LED on board */
while (1) {

    /* Sleep until a state change occurs in SysTick */
    while (lastState == state) {
        __WFI();
    }


    E2PROM_Read(I2C_TEMP_ADDR_7BIT, read_address, 2, in_buffer);
```

This is what I get from the logic analyzer, I write both addresses correctly, but receive the same byte instead of two different bytes (one for each address).

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you are forgetting to check and/or clear a flag register.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but shouldn't it send both bytes if I have sent the write to 0x28 and 0x29 properly? I mean I receive the data from 0x28 fine, but twice, and in the same function I specifically say read 2 bytes. (Also, I've removed code that was supposed to do all the I2C setup, and got structure of the program from here: https://fjrg76.wordpress.com/2014/12/11/reading-and-writing-a-24lc32a-eeprom-memory-using-the-lpcopen-framework-for-the-lpc1549-chip/ and seems to be doing the same. Thanks for the help. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your read function signature expects 16bit offset (read_address), however in the code this value is used incorrectly (assuming the EEPROM also expects 16bit offset). Replace {   out_buffer[0] = (uint8_t)(read_address);   out_buffer[1] = (uint8_t)(read_address + 0x01);  } with: {  out_buffer[0] = (uint8_t)(read_address & 0xff);  out_buffer[1] = (uint8_t)(read_address >> 8);  }